# Intellij auto-formatting - Adding a space after for keyword in for loop

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Can someone let me know how can I automatically add a space after `for` keyword in a for block in `Intellij 2017.3 Community Edition`? For example

```
for(String p : validPackages) {
   if(className.startsWith(p)) {
        return p;
   }
}
```

The above for loop to be auto formatted like below-

```
for (String p : validPackages) {
    if(className.startsWith(p)) {
        return p;
    }
}
```

Similarly for `while` block & `if` block.

Comment: CTRL + ALT + L to reformat code

Comment: Or right click on the file + Reformat Code with Rearrange entries selected

Comment: Is there a way I can auto-format the edited parts of a file whenever the file is saved?

Comment: I don't think so, but you get used to press this keys very quickly. I think you could delete your question as it has little to do with coding

Comment: Works fine for me, try default code style.  Are you typing it manually or using live templates or autocomplete?

Comment: Try cltr-alt-enter at the end of each line as you type. This adds any missing semi-colons and brackets and auto-formats the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `auto Completion` feature of `intellij`.
just type `fo` then autocompletion will show some suggestions hit `Enter`.
or reformat your Code using 
`CTRL +ALT +L`